# $.post() doesnt call php

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a simple form with message and email input. After i validate email i send data through jquery.post() like this:

```
if (validateEmail(mail)) {

                var data = $('#kontakt').serialize();
                alert(data);
                  $.post('mail.php', data);

        }
```

And mail.php like this:

```
<?php

    echo "Mail: ". $_POST['mail'];
?>
```

I tried header in php and it wont even redirect... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you open mail.php in your browser (without AJAX)?

Comment: What is the data shown in the alert? And how do you check whether anything is posted? Because in the code shown you're not doing anything with the result returned by the ajax request. Did you check in the browser-console whether anything is sent and returned?

Comment: Thankss guys i checked in browser console and changed the path to php script. Even though that my .js and .php file were in the same folder i had to specify the full path.. How come is that?? Anyways its working now ... Thanks on fast replies !

Comment: The ajax call is relative to the location of the webpage that runs the javascript, not relative to the the location of the javascript file. So unless your webpage is in the same location as well, that would explain why you need to specify the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the path to mail.php is correct.

Relative/Absolute path can sometime be tricky.